# Ubuntu 16.04 not restart on my Dell Inspiron 1018

Tags: xubuntu, dell, restart

I had installed Xubuntu 16.04 and everything was well, however, when I try restart for first time, my laptop first show next text...

/dev/sda5: clean, 168907/1875968 files, 937382/7499776 blocks
_

And It stay here for too time, still I reboot and everything turn to repeat again. So Xubuntu not start correctly on my PC. I have tried install Ubuntu 16.04, with the same result. Maybe It will be anything related Startup Implementation, I don't know it. I need your help, Thanks.
Note: I am sorry If I write some mistake with my english, I speak Spanish, greets.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/default/grub`. In the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` add an option
`systemd.restore_state=0`. After that run `sudo update-grub` and restart. This solved for me.

Comment: anyways, I am searching all around to find why my Dell Inspiron Mini with Lubuntu doesn't wake up from suspend. Tell me what is situation at yours.